# Sticky Header making image disappear off screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have put a sticky header on to my site which you can see here: http://tinyurl.com/mhcls2w

But as you can see, once you have scrolled 400px for the menu to jump to the top of the screen, the first image also jumps up and is no longer visible on screen.

At the point of 400px where the menu sticks, I would also like the image to be back on screen so must need a minus 400px somewhere, but how do I achieve this?

Thanks, Adrian

Comment: please port markup, not a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done a solution like this myself, so I have only a thought without actual testing.

Why not just have your sticky menu collapsed till 400px and don't have the menu sharing same .css styles? This way the bigger menu gets pushed up like normal and the other one appears without affecting the other content on the screen.

**Solution:** The other solution, which is probably exactly what you are looking for is to set the height: 400px; for id="headerwrapper" after the 400px has passed. That achieves the same and the image appears.

Comment: your other solution of adding 400px height to wrapper worked a treat, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Theres isn't a single solution for what you are looking for, Because to do what you want to do you must change the page scrollOffset while adding a marging or padding to the homebg1 div.

In my opinion instead of changing the header format at 400px i simply would duplicate the header , one per each scenario, and hide the sticky one when i don't need it.